# how to use Metrics Filter - Cost (Adcost) on google analytic source with SSIS?

Tags: c#, ssis, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to add a filter for Cost on metrics by saying return me only those having Cost > 0. But obvioulsy according to the type definition on this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords&jump=ga_adcost), type is currency and I am getting error that 0 is not valid. So filter as shown in the image isnt a valid one. how do I do it? any Idea?

[image]

Comment: Think you are better off contacting the author of that Data source reader. Questions about software are off topic for stack

Comment: If you can handle having the rows coming back to the data flow, you can add a Conditional Split to the flow and then filter the rows.

Comment: @billinkc thanks for your suggestion. Indeed I tried it and it is same problem there because of It require a conversion but i dont know how to convert currency type which is bigdecimal I guess. on the other hand, if there is an option, it would be more ideal to get results filtered already. thanks for your help.